# GROUP_CONCAT: получить данные в нужном порядке

Tags: php, mysql

пытаюсь получить 4 адреса из другой таблицы по их ID

есть запрос:

```
select ld.*, GROUP_CONCAT(le.url) as urls
from links_data as ld
inner join links_extra as le on 
ld.userURL1=le.id or ld.partnerURL1=le.id or ld.partnerURL2=le.id  or ld.userURL2=le.id
```

в `urls` все ссылки появляются нормально, но порядок не такой, т.е нужно что бы сортировка была именно такой: `userURL1,partnerURL1,partnerURL2,userURL2`

подскажите как это сделать? спасибо!

Comment: `group_concat(... ORDER BY case ....)` видимо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться следующим запросом:

```
    select 
        ld.*, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(le.url order by 
            ld.userURL1=le.id desc,
            ld.partnerURL1=le.id desc,
            ld.partnerURL2=le.id  desc,
            ld.userURL2=le.id
        ) as urls
    from links_data as ld
    inner join links_extra as le on 
        ld.userURL1=le.id or 
        ld.partnerURL1=le.id or 
        ld.partnerURL2=le.id  or 
        ld.userURL2=le.id
    group by 
        id,
        userURL1,
        partnerURL1,
        userURL2,
        partnerURL2
    ;
```

[MySQL песочница](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=3299319d91c99b953c8ed92167301162&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)